# mysqlclient fails to install within virtual environment

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

Outside my VE, mysqlclient is already installed and works fine, but when I try 'pip install mysqlclient' within my VE I get the following error:

"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 64-bit windows

install using wheel

**pip install wheel**
download from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)

For python 3.x:

**pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl**

For python 2.7:

**pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl**